# Tag synonym for multiple tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [wpf-4.0](/questions/tagged/wpf-4.0) tag is really a combination of [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0). The problem with this "unified" tag is the [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) may or may not be applied. So anyone viewing questions tagged with [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) will miss these questions.

Is this something that would normally be retagged to use [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0)? Or is there a way to make this a synonym of the two tags?