# partial subset tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

You should be able to see [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) results when you browse [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) or [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) tags.
In this case we can't use it as a synonym of both tags.

Could you implement **(1)** a tag *complementary/correlated* option or **(2)** a way to link several tags instead of one?

Expected result:

- [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) would
  redirect to (safari **or**
  google-chrome **or** webkit) [not and].
- [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) will contain [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) unique results (not [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ones)
- [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) will contain [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) unique results (not [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) ones)

related question: [Tag synonym for multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85356/tag-synonym-for-multiple-tags)

Comment: wow that title is almost as confusing as the tag synonym system :)

Comment: @waffles thx! :) I could rename it simply subset tag but it wouldn't attract much interest…

Answer (score 1):

Tag Hierarchy has been brought up many times before, see: [Tag hierarchy absence - design reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons)

We are slowly warming up to the idea, but do not have any concrete plans yet. Tag families introduce a slew of new performance considerations, so we need to ensure our infrastructure can handle the extra load before even considering.

Comment: in the meantime could you at least make it easier to use *OR* for tags? (related tag list on the right)

Comment: not really, OR type queries are too expensive at the moment, we can not afford to expose this for now